# Cancel 'Click' DOM event if CustomEvent fires on element

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom, dom-events, jquery-events

I'm building an app in Cordova and, as many apps have, I'm trying to implement long-press events that occur after holding down on an element.

I'm using https://github.com/john-doherty/long-press-event which fires a CustomEvent called 'long-press' after holding down on an element for 1.5 seconds.

I have an element I'd like to put both a 'Click' listener and a 'long-press' listener on, similar to many mobile apps such as photo galleries or email that react differently between a click and a long-press event.

The long-press event does fire, but the 'Click' event also fires every time and I can't find how or when I should try to stop it from firing. I've tried several placements of `stopDefault()` and `stopPropogation()` to no avail.

The HTML with a listener is

```html
<div class="grid-col grid-col--1">
    <div class="grid-item bd bdrs-4 bdw-1 bdc-grey-400">
        <img class="portfolio-img lightbox-img" src="https://glamsquad.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/GlamSquad/artist/1/portfolio/2019-05-16-06-07-370bc89b7bfe9769740c1f68f7e103340a94aaaeaa5d6f139f841e3c022ad309de.png">
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item bd bdrs-4 bdw-1 bdc-grey-400">
        <img class="portfolio-img lightbox-img" src="https://glamsquad.sgp1.cdn.digitaloceanspaces.com/GlamSquad/artist/1/portfolio/2019-05-16-06-07-38d8d03cc6edef043d25e9099b883cd235c823a267ab03b9e740934f06c4f87e2f.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

while the JS code is listening for a click on a lightbox-img, or a long-press on a portfolio image

```
$(document).on('long-press', '.portfolio-img', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Portfolio long press event.');
 });
$(document).on('click', '.lightbox-img', imageClick);
```

Is there any actual way to fire the long-press event but have it cancel or stop the click event from occurring?

Comment: I think @archer answer below works. you can try to understand the difference in timing of click call, by adding console log in both the functions. The long press event will have a time delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this, is to disable the `pointer-events` from your clicked element from the moment your `long-press` event fired, and until the next `mouseup` event fires on the document.

The best would probably to make it from your library, so here is a fork of this library which does now expose a `preventDefaultClick()` method on the CustomEvent:

```js
(function (window, document) {

    'use strict';

    var timer = null;

    // check if we're using a touch screen
    var isTouch = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));

    // switch to touch events if using a touch screen
    var mouseDown = isTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
    var mouseOut = isTouch ? 'touchcancel' : 'mouseout';
    var mouseUp = isTouch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';
    var mouseMove = isTouch ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove';

    // wheel/scroll events
    var mouseWheel = 'mousewheel';
    var wheel = 'wheel';
    var scrollEvent = 'scroll';

    // patch CustomEvent to allow constructor creation (IE/Chrome)
    if (typeof window.CustomEvent !== 'function') {

        window.CustomEvent = function(event, params) {

            params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };

            var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
            evt.initCustomEvent(event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail);
            return evt;
        };

        window.CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;
    }

    // listen to mousedown event on any child element of the body
    document.addEventListener(mouseDown, function(e) {
        var el = e.target;
        // get delay from html attribute if it exists, otherwise default to 1500
        var longPressDelayInMs = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-long-press-delay') || '1500', 10);
        // start the timer
        timer = setTimeout(fireLongPressEvent.bind(el, e), longPressDelayInMs);
    });

    // clear the timeout if the user releases the mouse/touch
    document.addEventListener(mouseUp, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear the timeout if the user leaves the element
    document.addEventListener(mouseOut, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear if the mouse moves
    document.addEventListener(mouseMove, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear if the Wheel event is fired in the element
    document.addEventListener(mouseWheel, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear if the Scroll event is fired in the element
    document.addEventListener(wheel, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear if the Scroll event is fired in the element
    document.addEventListener(scrollEvent, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    /**
     * Fires the 'long-press' event on element
     * @returns {void}
     */
    function fireLongPressEvent() {
        var evt = new CustomEvent('long-press', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
        // Expose a method to prevent the incoming click event
        var el = this;
        evt.preventDefaultClick = function() {
          // disable all pointer-events
          el.style["pointer-events"] = "none";
          // reenable at next mouseUp
          document.addEventListener(mouseUp, e => {
            el.style["pointer-events"] = "all";
          }, {once: true});
        };
        // fire the long-press event
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

}(window, document));

btn.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('clicked'));
btn.addEventListener('long-press', e => {
  console.log('long-press');
  e.preventDefaultClick(); // prevents the incoming 'click' event
});
```

```html
<button data-long-press-delay="500" id="btn">click me</button>
```

But if like me yo have a mouse that does fire a bunch of events at every swipe, then you might prefer this demo where the wheel etc timeout triggers have been disabled:

```js
(function (window, document) {

    'use strict';

    var timer = null;

    // check if we're using a touch screen
    var isTouch = (('ontouchstart' in window) || (navigator.maxTouchPoints > 0) || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));

    // switch to touch events if using a touch screen
    var mouseDown = isTouch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown';
    var mouseOut = isTouch ? 'touchcancel' : 'mouseout';
    var mouseUp = isTouch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup';
    var mouseMove = isTouch ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove';

    // wheel/scroll events
    var mouseWheel = 'mousewheel';
    var wheel = 'wheel';
    var scrollEvent = 'scroll';

    // patch CustomEvent to allow constructor creation (IE/Chrome)
    if (typeof window.CustomEvent !== 'function') {

        window.CustomEvent = function(event, params) {

            params = params || { bubbles: false, cancelable: false, detail: undefined };

            var evt = document.createEvent('CustomEvent');
            evt.initCustomEvent(event, params.bubbles, params.cancelable, params.detail);
            return evt;
        };

        window.CustomEvent.prototype = window.Event.prototype;
    }

    // listen to mousedown event on any child element of the body
    document.addEventListener(mouseDown, function(e) {
        var el = e.target;
        // get delay from html attribute if it exists, otherwise default to 1500
        var longPressDelayInMs = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-long-press-delay') || '1500', 10);
        // start the timer
        timer = setTimeout(fireLongPressEvent.bind(el, e), longPressDelayInMs);
    });

    // clear the timeout if the user releases the mouse/touch
    document.addEventListener(mouseUp, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear the timeout if the user leaves the element
    document.addEventListener(mouseOut, function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear if the mouse moves
    document.addEventListener(mouseMove, function() {
//        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear if the Wheel event is fired in the element
    document.addEventListener(mouseWheel, function() {
//        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear if the Scroll event is fired in the element
    document.addEventListener(wheel, function() {
//        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    // clear if the Scroll event is fired in the element
    document.addEventListener(scrollEvent, function() {
//        clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    /**
     * Fires the 'long-press' event on element
     * @returns {void}
     */
    function fireLongPressEvent() {
        var evt = new CustomEvent('long-press', { bubbles: true, cancelable: true });
        // Expose a method to prevent the incoming click event
        var el = this;
        evt.preventDefaultClick = function() {
          // disable all pointer-events
          el.style["pointer-events"] = "none";
          // reenable at next mouseUp
          document.addEventListener(mouseUp, e => {
            el.style["pointer-events"] = "all";
          }, {once: true});
        };
        // fire the long-press event
        this.dispatchEvent(evt);

        clearTimeout(timer);
    }

}(window, document));

btn.addEventListener('click', e => console.log('clicked'));
btn.addEventListener('long-press', e => {
  console.log('long-press');
  e.preventDefaultClick(); // prevents the incoming 'click' event
});
```

```html
<button data-long-press-delay="500" id="btn">click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! It works with the addition that the function is accessible at e.originalEvent.preventDefaultClick();

Comment: @Musa only if you did attach the listener with jQuery. In my snippet, there is no jQuery and no `originalEvent` on `evt`.

Comment: you're correct in pure javascript it works directly

Answer (score 0):

Propagation is not the problem here - it's the fact that a long click event and a regular click event are actually the same thing, so they both fire.  They're triggered because you do mouse down and then mouse up.  The fact that there's a longer wait between the 2 events does not stop the regular click from being fired.

The simplest way to handle this would be to set a flag that indicates whether the long-click event has been triggered, like this...

```
var longClickTriggered = false;

$(document).on('long-press', '.portfolio-img', (e) => {
    longClickTriggered = true;
    //e.preventDefault();   // these 2 lines are probably not needed now
    //e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('Portfolio long press event.');
});

$(document).on('click', '.lightbox-img', (e) => {
    if (!longClickTriggered) {
        imageClick();
    }
    longClickTriggered = false;
});
```

I commented these lines out...

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

because I believe they were only there in your attempt to stop the click event handler from firing.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a boolean, along with `mousedown` and `mouseup` listeners

```js
var timeoutId = 0, isHold = false;

$('#ele').on('mousedown', function() {
  timeoutId = setTimeout(onEleHold, 1000);
}).on('mouseup', function() {
  if (!isHold) {
    onEleClick();
  }
  isHold = false;
  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = 0;
});

function onEleHold() {
  console.log('hold');
  isHold = true;
}

function onEleClick() {
  console.log('click');
}
```

```css
#ele {
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ele">Click Here</div>
```